# RegEx disallow a character unless escaped

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, arguments, tokenize

below is my regex to parse comma separated key-value pairs:

```
function extractParams(str) {
    var result = {};
    str.replace(/\s*([^=,]+)\s*=\s*([^,]*)\s*/g, function(_, a, b) { result[a.trim()] = b.trim(); });
    return result;
}
```

For example the result of:

```
extractParams("arg1 = value1 ,arg2    = value2 ,arg3=uuu")
```

is 
`{"arg1":"value1","arg2":"value2","arg3":"uuu"}`.

I want to extend this function to allow the values include escaped commas, equals signs and the escape character itself. Such that the result of:

```
extractParams("arg1 = val\,ue1 ,arg2 = valu\=e2, arg3= val\\ue3")
```

will be

`{"arg1":"val,ue1","arg2":"valu=e2","arg3":"val\ue3"}`.

How can I do that? Thanks, Moshe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
function extractParams(str) {
    var result = {};
    str.replace(/\s*((?:\\[,\\=]|[^,\\=]*)+)\s*=\s*((?:\\[,\\=]|[^,\\=]*)+)\s*/g, function(_, a, b) { result[a.trim()] = b.trim(); });
    return result;
}

console.log(extractParams("arg1 = val\\,ue1 ,arg2 = valu\\=e2, arg3= val\\\\ue3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a pattern that might not even need escaping `\,` commas to tell them apart.

If we can assume that your **keys don't contain commas**, unlike the values, as in:

`ke y` `=` `,val,ue!` is OK
`k,ey` `=` `val,ue` is KO

Then the following pattern will work very well:

```
([^,]+)=(.+?)(?:(?=,[^,]+=)|$)
```

You can play with it here: [**https://regex101.com/r/RX4RsR/2**](https://regex101.com/r/RX4RsR/2)