# Regex should not contain a character unless

Tags: regex, scala

If I have a string like

```
foo&bar&baz
```

and I want to extract tokens foo, bar, baz from it. a regex is easy to write

```
val regex = "([^&]+)".r
regex.findAllIn("foo&bar&baz").map(_.toString).toList
```

This gives me the answer I want.

```
List("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

But the input can have the & symbol escaped with `_&_`

So if the input is

```
foo_&_bar&baz
```

The output should be foo&bar, baz.

I googled and found this thread which has similar problem

[RegEx disallow a character unless escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466141/regex-disallow-a-character-unless-escaped)

Based on this thread I changed my regex to

```
val regex = "((?:_&_|[^&]*)+)".r
```

But this doesn't work the output is

```
List("foo_", "", "_bar", "", "baz", "")
```

Comment: Try `(?:_&_|[^&])+`

Comment: Use `(?<=[^\W_])&(?=[^\W_])` to find instances of `&` that aren't surrounded by `_` and replace them with `,` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/iCeubF/1). Then replace all instances of `_&_` with `&` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/iCeubF/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
val regex = "(?:_&_|[^&])+".r
println( regex.findAllIn("foo_&_bar&baz").map(_.toString).toList )
// => List(foo_&_bar, baz)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZQPfQ/2) and a [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/JDK3777).

The `(?:_&_|[^&])+` regex matches 1 or more repetitons of `_&_` or, if not found at the current location, char other than `&`.

Comment: makes sense. but what is the need of the "?:" it's a non capturing group. why are we using that here?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch You are not using the pattern for pattern matching, hence there is no need for a capturing group in the regex (`findAllIn` does not require a capturing group in the regex pattern). Since we do not want the overhead of re-writing each subsequent `_&_` or non-`&` in the capturing group memory buffer, it makes sense to make the group [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).